# change multi-target project output path and file name

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a project in `D:\dev\app` with this configuration:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <TargetFrameworks>net48;net5.0-windows</TargetFrameworks>
        <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    </PropertyGroup>
    
</Project>
```

what should I add to force VS to generate the exe files as follow:

`D:\bin\app-net48.exe` for the `net48` target framework

`D:\bin\app-net50.exe` for the `net5.0-windows` target framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a couple of directives

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net48'">
    <AssemblyName>app-net48</AssemblyName>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net5.0-windows'">
    <AssemblyName>app-net50</AssemblyName>
</PropertyGroup>
```

surely, you can also use

```xml
<Choose>
   <When Condition="....">
      <PropertyGroup>
      </PropertyGroup>
   </When>
   <When Condition="....">
      <PropertyGroup>
      </PropertyGroup>
   </When>
</Choose>
```

[Reference link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditional-constructs?view=vs-2019)

use `<AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>` in the initial `<PropertyGroup>` to remove adding folder structures to the output

Comment: I tried to set <OutputPath>D:\bin\</OutputPath> and <AssemblyName>app-net48</AssemblyName> but VS creates the exe as "D:\bin\net5.0-windows\app-net48.exe" instead of "D:\bin\app-net48.exe"

Comment: @geek175 there is a different switch to stop adding a target framework folder

Comment: @geek175 `<AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>`

Comment: works like a charm please remove ".exe" from <AssemblyName> attribute and add <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath> and <OutputPath> to the answer so I can check it.